# PDO Select from table WHERE url != (SELECT)

Tags: sql, pdo

I have 2 db tables - one is including all the entries, the other one is the "blacklist" - means i want to select all values excluding the entries of table 2

```
$req = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE link_id != (SELECT id FROM table2)";
$stmt = $pdo->query($req);

foreach($stmt as $data) {

echo $data['link_id']."<br>";           

}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please include table schema such as what type id is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try NOT IN, like so:

`$req = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE link_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)";`

I think that would do what you're asking for, if I understand you correctly. It may not be the fastest way to do it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Although the selected answer works it is not efficient as the DB will need to do two seeks for the internal query and then again on the external query. The most efficient and effective query is a LEFT JOIN that removes the need for the second query.

```
SELECT b.* FROM names AS n LEFT JOIN blacklist_names AS b on n.id=b.id WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

You can alias the tables like I did or not. I did it to make the code shorter.

What the query is doing is matching all ids found in both tables and then excluding them from the results by taking whats left from the "all names list" that is not in the blacklist.

**EDIT:** As per the author, putting the solution here to highlight it from the comments.

```
SELECT spotify.ID,spotify.land,spotify.song,spotify.link_id,spotify.pos1 FROM spotify LEFT JOIN spotify_blacklist ON (spotify.link_id = spotify_blacklist.URL) WHERE spotify_blacklist.URL IS NULL ORDER BY spotify.song ASC
```

Comment: can you help me on this example? I don´t get it done.
`SELECT * FROM spotify WHERE pos1 > '0' AND pos1 <= '100' AND 
(land = 'GLOBAL' OR land = 'DE') AND 
link_id NOT IN (SELECT URL FROM spotify_blacklist) 
ORDER BY song ASC`

Comment: @SvenJanning Can you give me the table schema? What id do the tables share?

Comment: I think i already solved it. I had a duplicate entry and that was the reason why i didn´t work

Comment: Can you provide the query for me to include in the answer or edit your question so others can find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the correct code, which works for me -> 
`$abfrage = "SELECT spotify.ID,spotify.land,spotify.song,spotify.link_id,spotify.pos1 FROM spotify LEFT JOIN spotify_blacklist  ON (spotify.link_id = spotify_blacklist.URL) WHERE spotify_blacklist.URL IS NULL ORDER BY spotify.song ASC";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($abfrage);

$stmt->execute();`